# Selenium Grid Example Not Launching Correctly

Tags: java, ant, ubuntu-12.04, selenium-grid

I have some experience with selenium and running it through the IDE and Java programs using webdriver. I'm now looking at trying to do this with selenium grid to tie this in with the bamboo server that we're currently using. I've downloaded grid, and followed through the demo. I've launched the hub, and an RC, but the demo seems to launch firefox, and then just sit there.

My Java version:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am using the ant commands as ant is installed on this machine (Ubuntu 12.0.4).

Hub:

```
ant launch-hub
Buildfile: /home/seleniumgridhub/SeleniumGrid/selenium-grid-1.0.8/build.xml

launch-hub:
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:00:31 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.HubRegistry gridConfiguration
     [java] INFO: Loaded grid configuration:
     [java] --- 
     [java] hub: 
     [java]   environments: 
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*firefox"
     [java]       name: Firefox on Windows
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*firefox"
     [java]       name: Firefox on OS X
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*firefox"
     [java]       name: Firefox on Linux
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*iehta"
     [java]       name: IE on Windows
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*safari"
     [java]       name: Safari on OS X
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*firefox"
     [java]       name: "*firefox"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*firefox2"
     [java]       name: "*firefox2"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*firefox3"
     [java]       name: "*firefox3"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*chrome"
     [java]       name: "*chrome"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*iexplore"
     [java]       name: "*iexplore"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*iehta"
     [java]       name: "*iehta"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*safari"
     [java]       name: "*safari"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*opera"
     [java]       name: "*opera"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*googlechrome"
     [java]       name: "*googlechrome"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*firefoxproxy"
     [java]       name: "*firefoxproxy"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*pifirefox"
     [java]       name: "*pifirefox"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*iexploreproxy"
     [java]       name: "*iexploreproxy"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*piiexplore"
     [java]       name: "*piiexplore"
     [java]     - 
     [java]       browser: "*safariproxy"
     [java]       name: "*safariproxy"
     [java] 
     [java] 2013-06-26 14:00:31.999::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
     [java] 2013-06-26 14:00:32.053::INFO:  jetty-6.0.x
     [java] 2013-06-26 14:00:32.213::INFO:  Started SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:4444
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:09 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.management.RegistrationServlet process
     [java] INFO: Registering new remote control...
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:09 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.management.RegistrationServlet process
     [java] INFO: Registered [RemoteControlProxy localhost:5555#false]
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:50 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.HubServlet forward
     [java] INFO: Processing '1 => "*firefox", 2 => "http://images.google.com", 3 => "", cmd => "getNewBrowserSession"'
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:50 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.remotecontrol.RemoteControlProvisioner reserve
     [java] INFO: Reserved remote control[RemoteControlProxy localhost:5555#true]
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:03:32 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.remotecontrol.RemoteControlPoller garbageCollectRemoteControls
     [java] INFO: Garbage collecting unavailable RCs and stale sessions...
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:06:32 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.remotecontrol.RemoteControlPoller garbageCollectRemoteControls
     [java] INFO: Garbage collecting unavailable RCs and stale sessions...
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:09:32 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.remotecontrol.RemoteControlPoller garbageCollectRemoteControls
     [java] INFO: Garbage collecting unavailable RCs and stale sessions...
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:12:32 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.remotecontrol.RemoteControlPoller garbageCollectRemoteControls
     [java] INFO: Garbage collecting unavailable RCs and stale sessions...
```

RC:

```
ant launch-remote-control
Buildfile: /home/seleniumgridhub/SeleniumGrid/selenium-grid-1.0.8/build.xml

launch-remote-control:
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:09 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol.RegistrationRequest execute
     [java] INFO: Registering to http://localhost:4444/registration-manager/register
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:09 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl logStartingMessages
     [java] INFO: Starting selenium server with options:[RegistrationInfo seleniumHubURL='http://localhost:4444', env='*firefox', host='localhost', port='5555']
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:09 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl logStartingMessages
     [java] INFO: hubPollerInterval: 30000 ms
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:09 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl logStartingMessages
     [java] INFO: -port
     [java] Jun 26, 2013 2:01:09 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl logStartingMessages
     [java] INFO: 5555
     [java] 14:01:10.063 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.25-b01
     [java] 14:01:10.065 INFO - OS: Linux 3.5.0-34-generic amd64
     [java] 14:01:10.095 INFO - v2.0 [a2], with Core v2.0 [a2]
     [java] 14:01:10.267 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://10.211.55.22:5555/wd/hub
     [java] 14:01:10.268 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
     [java] 14:01:10.269 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
     [java] 14:01:10.274 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
     [java] 14:01:10.274 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
     [java] 14:01:10.287 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@54c8d4b4
     [java] 14:01:10.287 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
     [java] 14:01:10.289 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
     [java] 14:01:10.289 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1a10540f
     [java] 14:01:39.993 INFO - Checking connection to hub...
     [java] 14:01:39.994 INFO - Ping Hub at http://localhost:4444/heartbeat?host=localhost&port=5555
     [java] 14:01:50.960 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
     [java] 14:01:50.964 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox, http://images.google.com, ] on session null
     [java] 14:01:50.966 INFO - creating new remote session
     [java] 14:01:51.092 INFO - Allocated session d0dd7e782dd34fa287bdff20a4e48cd9 for http://images.google.com, launching...
     [java] 14:01:51.171 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
     [java] 14:01:54.266 INFO - Launching Firefox...
     [java] 14:02:10.048 INFO - Checking connection to hub...
     [java] 14:02:10.048 INFO - Ping Hub at http://localhost:4444/heartbeat?host=localhost&port=5555
```

Comment: It happened to me when having wrong/incompatible selenium libraries' versions. First, check what version of selenium grid you are trying to configure: 1 or 2. There are many demos on the net that refer to v.1 and it has significant differences with v.2. (I suppose you are trying with v.2) I am using selenium grid 2 ('selenium-java' and 'selenium-server-standalone', both 2.32.0) and it works fine with the last version of Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using selenium webdriver, you must use [Selenium Grid 2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

Download the [selenium server](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar) from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) (As of the time of this answer- version 33)

Then start the hub by running this command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role hub
```

and a node (capability to run BOTH selenium RC and webdriver scripts) -

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Hopefully you can figure it out from here.

Comment: Not that I know of. But why do you care?

Comment: Idea was originally to have an ant build.xml file start and stop these servers as needed, but ultimately, you're right it doesn't matter too much. Just a nice to have thing.

Comment: Great. If this answer helped, you can mark this as the solution like so
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235